# Objective-c Array Learning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Okay I am learning about arrays and how to work with them like  I used to...... (Used to do alot of scripting but now am trying to learn to develop ipad and iphone app's

But my issue is I have it where it pulls a bunch of data from yahoo finance with a for loop..

But now my issue is how can I work with just one peice of the array data that has been pulled

here is my example

```
-(IBAction) clicked:(id)sender {

   NSString * StockOneYahooFinance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=S+Historical+Prices"];
   NSString * PulledStockOne = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StockOneYahooFinance] encoding:1 error:nil];

   for (i=1;i<=10;i++){

      NSString *StartPulling = [[PulledStockOne componentsSeparatedByString:@"nowrap align="] objectAtIndex:i];

      NSString *StartOpen = [[StartPulling componentsSeparatedByString:@">"] objectAtIndex:3];
      NSString *Open = [[StartOpen componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"] objectAtIndex:0];

      NSString *StartClose = [[StartPulling componentsSeparatedByString:@">"] objectAtIndex:9];
      NSString *Close = [[StartClose componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"] objectAtIndex:0];

      NSMutableArray *StockOpens = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];
      [StockOpens addObject:Open];


      sixtyday.text = [OpenValues objectAtIndex:10];
      nintyday.text = [CloseValues objectAtIndex:10];


      if ([OpenValues objectAtIndex:10]=[OpenValues objectAtIndex:11] {
         sevenday.text = @"Plus One";
      } 
   }
}
```

But now I want to do something like

```
year.text=StockOpens[5];
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Xcode 4.4 (LLVM 4.0), literals can be used for C-style subscripting in Objective-C.

```
year.text = StockOpens[5];
```

LLVM has documented the use of literal here: [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Note: Because Clang will translate the literal usage, in this case to `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`, the OS X v10.8 (or iOS 6) Foundation framework is required.

Comment: Is there something similar for dictionary keys aswell? Nice!

Comment: Yes there is! I updated my solution with a link to LLVM's documentation.

Comment: Note that this also requires use of the Foundation version that accompanies the iOS 6 or OS X 10.8 SDKs.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right, I'll add that to the solution.

Comment: I'm not able to test this, but wouldn't `@5` be used as a dictionary keyword, while `5` would be used as an array index?

Comment: I was thinking NSNumber for the index, but it's actually NSUInteger.

Comment: Okay First I want to thank you for the quick response You have really helped me and it makes a lot of since and worked great but now my only issue is that if i have all the code below I am returning a error I belive this is because the numbers that are pulled from the website are still in nsstring format but I have tried to convert them to int's but there is something wrong maybe you can help

I couldnt paste the code here so I changed the code above in the orginal question

thank you so very much your awsome

Comment: LValue required as left operand of assignment
Expected; before OBJC_STRiNG' Token

Comment: It's most likely the line `if ([OpenValues objectAtIndex:10]=[OpenValues objectAtIndex:11]{`. Should be ==, not =. If you are comparing strings though, you need to use `isEqual:`. The == operator will compare the pointers.

Comment: Thank you I will research it through out today and see what I come up with and thank you so much for your help but dont be suprised if I have to ask for some more of your knowledge lol

Answer (score 1):

StockOpens is an array object so you need to call a method to get the object at an index. On NSMutableArray its [StockOpens ObjectAtIndex:5]

```
year.text = [[StockOpens objectAtIndex:5]StringValue];
```

To do StockOpens[5] you need to use a C-array.

Comment: Just an amplification: @user1544586: if you are accustomed to bracket access to arrays from scripting languages, it doesn't work like that in Obj-C. Also you can't store primitive values in arrays (ints, floats); they need to be converted to one of the NSObject-based classes (NSNUmber, NSValue, etc.).

Comment: @skinnyTOD In objective-c 2.5, you now can, with `objectAtSubscriptedIndex`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - First I have heard. Is that supported in iOS 6?

Comment: Probably a compiler directive. So shouldn't it be supported by all OS?

Comment: @MrAzulay: It is largely a compiler feature, but it's syntactic sugar for a method call. Versions of the framework earlier than that accompanying iOS 6/Mac OS X 10.8 don't include the necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind/class of objects you fill `StockOpens` with, if it's simply NSStrings, you can do

```
year.text = [StockOpens objectAtIndex:5];
```

If it's some other object that is not a string, you can maybe call its description:

```
year.text = [[StockOpens objectAtIndex:5] description];
```

P. s.: there's documentation on developer.apple.com, please read it! This question is so simple (and fundamental) that it must not be asked on SO.